# Можно ли как-то в строковых ресурсах дополнять строку?

Tags: java, android

Вот в чем вопрос, мое приложение работает с сервером и есть несколько адресов по которым приложение общается с сервером

Вот так это выглядит

```
<string name="url_app_login">http://52.58.65.000/applogin</string>
<string name="url_create_user_avatar_response">http://52.58.65.000/createuseravatarrespone</string>
<string name="url_create_user_avatar">http://52.58.65.000/createuseravatar</string>
<string name="url_app_reg">http://52.58.65.000/appreg</string>
<string name="url_app_res_pass">http://52.58.65.000/apprespass</string>
<string name="url_get_avatar">http://52.58.65.000/mservices/getuseravatar/id=</string>
<string name="url_check_name_exist">http://52.58.65.000/checknameexist</string>
<string name="url_reg_user">http://52.58.65.000/reguser</string>
```

Можно ли как-то вынести `http://52.58.65.000/` в переменную и остальное чтоб добавлялось?

Не вынося это в код, чтоб это все дальше продолжало быть ресурсами...

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь это невозможно. Наверное вам стоит вынести адрес хоста в отдельный строковый ресурс а различные пути также в отдельные и в самом коде уже конкатенировать.
То есть у вас есть строка сервер

```
<string name="server">http://server</string>
```

И есть отдельно пути

```
<string name="path1">path1</string>
<string name="path2">path2</string>
```

Сам путь объявлен так

```
<string name="url">%s/%s</string>
```

Ну и собственно в коде

```
Resources res = getResources();
String url = res.getString(R.string.url, res.getString(R.string.server), res.getString(R.string.path1));
```

Comment: Я тут посмотрел, можно без getResources(). Напрямую вызвать getString()